# PayPal IPN - Can it notify of payments SENT, rather than received?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to make my accounting easier and looking for solutions to connect PayPal to Xero to create bills/payments for Sent payments, not payments I receive. Is there away for IPN to deal with sent payments?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're sending the money.

If you use the Send Money feature within PayPal.com then you would get an IPN with **txn_type = send_money**.

If you send money via the MassPay API you would get a single IPN with **txn_type = masspay** that covers all the payments included in that MassPay transaction.

If you use the Adaptive Payments Pay API you could setup an app specific notification within your Pay request using the ipnNotificationUrl parameter.  This will trigger an IPN when payments are sent through your app, but the details in these app specific IPNs aren't always ideal as they are sometimes limited.

Comment: Thanks Andrew,

Most of the payments made are through the PayPal IOS app, individual payments up to maybe 5 of them per day sometimes.

Which of these methods could still work?

Comment: I've never specifically tested that, but I think that would be considered send_money.  You'll need to setup an IPN solution and test it.